# How to svn-merge a directory into a branch where it originally didn't exist

Tags: svn, merge

Suppose the following structure on an svn server:

```
-svn-|
     |-trunk --- |
     |           | - dirA
     |           | - dirB
     |
     |-branches -|
                 | - foo - |
                           | - dirA
```

At a revision X, the foo branch was created from the trunk. Some time later at revision Y, directory dirB was created in the trunk. Now, at revision Z, i want to integrate dirB (rev Z) into the foo branch.

I tried:

```
md dirB
svn add dirB
svn merge --dry-run --force ssh://server/svn/trunk/dirB dirB
```

and

```
svn merge -rY:Z--dry-run --force ssh://server/svn/trunk/dirB dirB
```

and also

```
cd dirB
svn merge --dry-run --force ssh://server/svn/trunk/dirB .
```

Everytime I get

```
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 34
```

How to do this merge?

Comment: I think you may be complicating. `svn cp` seems does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you're in working copy `dirA`

```
cd branches/foo/dirA
```

Merge `dirB` into `foo/dirA`

```
svn merge ssh://server/svn/trunk/dirB .
```

**EDIT:**
Branches are created using `svn cp`:

```
svn cp ssh://server/svn/trunk/dirB ssh://server/svn/branches/foo/dirB -m"dirB branch created"
```

Comment: This way I get the contents of dirB into dirA. What I want is (as in the trunk) dirB as a separate directory besides dirA. And I keep getting the tree conflicts either way.

Comment: @Philipp: Hope my additional comment answers your question.

Comment: bless you for this command, this is only way i've found to "create" branch.. i came from git so for me svn is hell...